# Get updated row as XML

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to get the last updated row as XML in sql server?

Consider this snippet

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    NAME NVARCHAR(255)
    ,Col2 INT
    )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES (
    'a1'
    ,1
    )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES (
    'a2'
    ,2
    )

UPDATE @table
SET NAME = 'hello'
OUTPUT inserted.* 
WHERE Col2 = 2
```

The above statements outputs the updated row. How can I output the row as XML, as I would do with a `SELECT` statement?

I tried the `SELECT` syntax, but was unsuccessful.

```
UPDATE @table
SET NAME = 'hello'
OUTPUT (inserted.* FOR XML AUTO)
WHERE Col2 = 2
```

Is there any way to accomplish this other than writing it to a table and selecting from the table?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to accomplish this other than writing it to a table
>   and selecting from the table?

Not that I know of. Create a table variable where you insert the output from the update and then use that to create the XML output you want.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  NAME NVARCHAR(255),
  Col2 INT
);

INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('a1', 1);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('a2', 2);

DECLARE @updateresult TABLE
(
  NAME NVARCHAR(255),
  Col2 INT
);

UPDATE @table
SET NAME = 'hello'
OUTPUT inserted.NAME, 
       inserted.Col2 
INTO @updateresult(Name, Col2)
WHERE Col2 = 2

SELECT NAME, Col2
FROM @updateresult
FOR XML PATH('row');
```